# What is wrong with my Simpson algorithm?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I was trying to write an algorithm to approximate integrals with Simpson's method. When I try to plot it in a loglog plot, however, I don't get the correct order of accuracy which is O(h^4) (I get O(n)). I can't find any errors though. This is my code:

```
%Reference solution with Simpson's method (the reference solution works well)
yk = 0;
yj = 0;
href = 0.0001;
mref = (b-a)/href;

for k=2:2:mref-1
    yk=yk+y(k*href+a);
end

for j=1:2:mref
    yj=yj+y(href*j+a);
end
Iref=(href/3)*(y(a)+y(b)+2*yk+4*yj);

%Simpson's method
iter = 1;
Ehmatrix = 0;
for n = 0:nmax
    h = b/(2^n+1);
    x = a:h:b;
    xodd = x(2:2:end-1);
    xeven = x(3:2:end);
    yodd = y(xodd);
    yeven = y(xeven);
    Isimp = (h/3)*(y(x(1))+4*sum(yodd)+2*sum(yeven)+y(b));
    E = abs(Isimp-Iref);
    Ehmatrix([iter],1) = [E];
    Ehmatrix([iter],2) = [h];
    iter = iter + 1;
end

figure
loglog(Ehmatrix(:,2),Ehmatrix(:,1))
```

a and b are the integration limits and y is the integrand that we want to approximate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account Geoff's suggestions, and making a few other changes, it all works as expected.

```
%Reference solution with Simpson's method (the reference solution works well)
a=0;
b=1;
y=@(x) cos(x);
nmax=10;

%Simpson's method
Ehmatrix = [];
for n = 0:nmax
    x = linspace(a,b,2^n+1);
    h = x(2)-x(1);
    xodd = x(2:2:end-1);
    xeven = x(3:2:end-1);
    yodd = y(xodd);
    yeven = y(xeven);
    Isimp = (h/3)*(y(x(1))+4*sum(yodd)+2*sum(yeven)+y(b));
    E = abs(Isimp-integral(y,0,1));
    Ehmatrix(n+1,:) = [E h];
end

loglog(Ehmatrix(:,2),Ehmatrix(:,1))

P=polyfit(log(Ehmatrix(:,2)),log(Ehmatrix(:,1)),1);    
OrderofAccuracy=P(1)
```

You were getting `O(h)` accuracy because `xeven=x(3:2:end)` was wrong. Replacing it by `xeven=x(3:e:end-1)` fixes the code, and thus the accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

Djamillah - your code looks fine though the initialization of `h` is probably valid only for the case where `a==0`, so you may want to change this line of code to

```
h = (b-a)/(2^n+1);
```

I wonder if `x = a:h:b;` will always be valid - sometimes `b` may be included in the list, and sometimes it might not be, depending upon `h`.  You may want to reconsider and use `linspace` instead

```
x = linspace(a,b,2^n+1);
```

which will guarantee that `x` has 2^n+1 points distributed evenly in the interval `[a,b]`.  `h` could then be initialized as

```
h = x(2)-x(1);
```

Also, when determining the even and odd indices, we need to ignore the last element of `x` for both even and odd.  So instead of

```
xodd  = x(2:2:end-1);
xeven = x(3:2:end);
```

do

```
xodd  = x(2:2:end-1);
xeven = x(3:2:end-1);
```

Finally, rather than using a vector `y` (how is this set?) I might just use the function handle to the function that I'm integrating instead and replace the calculation above as

```
Isimp = delta/3*(func(x(1)) + 4*sum(func(xodd)) + 2*sum(func(xeven)) + ...
        func(x(end)));
```

Other than these tiny things (which are probably negligible), there is nothing in your algorithm to indicate a problem.  It produced similar results to a version that I have.

As for the order of convergence, should it be `O(n^4)` or `O(h^4)`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean order of convergence but order of accuracy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_accuracy) so it should be O(h^4). The slope of the graph in the loglog-plot should be 4 but I get it to 1. y is set as a function handle on the form y=@(x)...